# Weird result from DBPedia

Tags: dbpedia

I'm trying to query a list of all airports and their IATA code:

```
PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?airport ?iata ?name 
WHERE {
    ?airport rdf:type o:Airport ;
     p:iata ?iata ;
     p:name ?name 
}
ORDER by ?airport
```

[Executing it](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+p%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+o%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fairport+%3Fiata+%3Fname+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fairport+rdf%3Atype+o%3AAirport+%3B%0D%0A+++++p%3Aiata+%3Fiata+%3B%0D%0A+++++p%3Aname+%3Fname+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+by+%3Fairport&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) looks mostly fine, but there are some weird blocks where airport get assigned the wrong name, such as:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Abdul_Majeed_bin_Abdul_Aziz_Domestic_Airport  "ULH"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Albert_(Glass_Field)_Airport                  "YPA"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_George_Airport                                "YXS"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Mohammad_Bin_Abdulaziz_Airport                "MED"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Rupert/Seal_Cove_Water_Airport                "ZSW"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Rupert_Airport                                "YPR"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Said_Ibrahim_International_Airport            "HAH"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Princess_Juliana_International_Airport               "SXM"@en   "Prince Abdul Majeed bin Abdul Aziz Airport"@en
```

Besides all having "Prince" in their name they seem to have nothing in common. Clicking through to the resource also suggests no relation to the name they've been assigned.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - found solution:**

Removing "ORDER by ?airport" or changing it to "ORDER by ?iata" fixes the problem.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but there are some other strange ones, too.  E.g., there are five with the name "Presidente Carlos Ibáñez International Airport"@en, nine with "Puerto Barrios Airport"@en, three with "Punta Cana International Airport"@en, two "Queen Alia International Airport"@en, and http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rafael_Cabrera_Mustelier_Airport shows up twice, just to name a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBpedia ontology (`dbpedia-owl`) data tends to be a bit cleaner than the older infobox data  (`dbprop`), so I thought you might want to use a query that uses the `dbpedia-owl` properties:

```
SELECT ?airport ?iata ?name
WHERE {
    ?airport a dbpedia-owl:Airport ;
             dbpedia-owl:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata ;
             rdfs:label ?name .
    FILTER langMatches( lang( ?name ), "EN" )
}
order by ?airport
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?airport%20?iata%20?name%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?airport%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aAirport%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aiataLocationIdentifier%20?iata%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?name%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%20?name%20%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?airport&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The data is somewhat better, but there are still some bizarre results like:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Albert_(Glass_Field)_Airport "YPA"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_George_Airport   "YXS"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Mohammad_Bin_Abdulaziz_Airport   "MED"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Rupert/Seal_Cove_Water_Airport   "ZSW"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Rupert_Airport   "YPR"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Said_Ibrahim_International_Airport   "HAH"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Princess_Juliana_International_Airport  "SXM"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Princeton_Airport_(New_Jersey)  "PCT"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
```

In the interest of trying a few different approaches, I also decided to try grouping by the `?airport` and `?iata`, and then sampling the name:

```
SELECT ?airport ?iata sample(?name)
WHERE {
    ?airport a dbpedia-owl:Airport ;
             dbpedia-owl:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata ;
             rdfs:label ?name .
    FILTER langMatches( lang( ?name ), "EN" )
}
group by ?airport ?iata
order by ?airport
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?airport%20?iata%20sample%28?name%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?airport%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aAirport%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aiataLocationIdentifier%20?iata%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?name%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%20?name%20%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?airport%20?iata%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?airport&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This gets different, but equally strange results, e.g.:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/%22Solidarity%22_Szczecin-Goleni%C3%B3w_Airport "SZZ"@en    ""Solidarity" Szczecin-Goleniów Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%81ngel_Albino_Corzo_International_Airport   "TGZ"@en    ""Solidarity" Szczecin-Goleniów Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%84ngelholm-Helsingborg_Airport  "AGH"@en    ""Solidarity" Szczecin-Goleniów Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%85lesund_Airport,_Vigra "AES"@en    ""Solidarity" Szczecin-Goleniów Airport"@en
http://dbpedia.org/resource/%C3%85re_%C3%96stersund_Airport "OSD"@en    ""Solidarity" Szczecin-Goleniów Airport"@en
```

And yet, if we group by name instead, and select the name and count the number of airports with a given name, we get `1` across the board, but some *names* appear twice!

```
SELECT count(?airport) ?name
WHERE {
    ?airport a dbpedia-owl:Airport ;
             dbpedia-owl:iataLocationIdentifier ?iata ;
             rdfs:label ?name .
    FILTER langMatches( lang( ?name ), "EN" )
}
group by ?name
order by ?name
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20count%28?airport%29%20?name%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?airport%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aAirport%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aiataLocationIdentifier%20?iata%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?name%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20langMatches%28%20lang%28%20?name%20%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?name%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?name&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
1   "Abraham González International Airport"@en
1   "Abraham González International Airport"@en
...
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
1   "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
```

This truly is bizarre.  It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with your query, but that something weird is going on over at DBpedia.  You can take a look at some of these strange entries, and the data that DBpedia will show doesn't match these results.  For instance, one of the results from the original query is

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Prince_Mohammad_Bin_Abdulaziz_Airport   "MED"@en    "Prince Albert (Glass Field) Airport"@en
```

but if you visit http://dbpedia.org/page/Prince_Mohammad_Bin_Abdulaziz_Airport and search the page for "Albert", you won't find it there.

Comment: Removing the "order by" clause works. There's gotta be something that truncates the (long) URL for ordering and that screws up .. something.